# jQuery slideToggle issue in Safari and Chrome

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

if you use the link below and click on the Search button on the table header you will see that it slides down too far before having to jump back up. This only happens in Safari and Chrome, Firefox on IE are fine?

http://www.search-this.com/examples/adv-table-search/tableAndSearch.htm

Any ideas? THanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the `fixed` class from your `advSearch` table seems to correct the problem:

So, instead of:

```
<table cellspacing="0" class="widefat fixed" id="advSearch">
```

Use:

```
<table cellspacing="0" class="widefat" id="advSearch">
```